# Typescript error -- Error: Cannot find module 'typescript/tsc.js'

Tags: node.js, typescript, module, tsc

I cannot figure out how to make my 'tsc' command working:

```
tsc
module.js:472
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'typescript/tsc.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
```

My 'package.json' has:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^14.11.2",
    "tslib": "^2.0.1",
    "typedoc": "^0.19.2",
    "typescript": "^4.0.3"
  }
```

And my 'tsconfig.json':

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationDir": "dist/types",
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "lib": [
      "es2019"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

No error during 'npm install'.

When I check up the 'node_modules' folder, typescript exists and the 'tsc.js' file exists within the 'typescript/lib' directory.

node --version: 12.18.4

npm --version: 6.14.6

system: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

I have tried many of the solution proposed for a similar issue without success:

- delete the node_modules folder and then run npm install again
- try to reinstall manually: *npm install typescript --save-dev*
- using: *npm install typescript-tools --save-dev*
- ...

None of the above gets me any result.
Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who gets stuck with that, the command that should be run with your **local tsc** is:

`npx tsc`

Answer (score 2):

To make the `tsc --version` command working, try to install using `npm install -g typescript` command. It installs the typescript globally.