# Error on execute ng serve : "An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module 'typescript'"

Tags: angular, typescript, serve

That's error happens to me, when i just created a new Angular project and execute `ng serve`. The Line of error is: *An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module 'typescript'*. After stop and read the error, i found the rason for this. Forgeted to change the location after project creation. For exemplo, on my project "crud-angular", was run `cd crud-angular`. Now, on folder contains all project files, run `ng serve` and be hapy!

Comment: While [self-answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) are encouraged in Stack Exchange, the question section is generally reserved only for the question. You could write an answer and mark it as resolved. On the other hand, it appears there already is a specific post for this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67419621/6513921

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it’s not an actual question (and likely a duplicate anyway)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript error -- Error: Cannot find module 'typescript/tsc.js'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64081087/typescript-error-error-cannot-find-module-typescript-tsc-js)